# Memory thing about modifiers

Tags: java

I was thinking about that is there any difference between those modifiers in Java. E.g: I have an int value.:
    public int;
    private int;
    public static int;
    private static int;
    public final int = ?;
    private static final int = ?;
Because I see in Minecraft resource locations are private static final. Is there any difference between them by memory consumption?

Comment: You should worry more about good design, good abstractions, data structures and algorithms and less about memory consumption… memory is cheap and abundant nowadays.

Comment: What is "lots of memory"? In Java, you should start to worry only when your program hits, say, 2-4 GB (assuming a server-side program). Anything less is simply not worth the time, don't worry about reducing memory consumption _just yet_. There are tons of more important things to take care of, micro-optimizing the code for reducing memory footprint is a waste of time _unless_ a profiler demonstrates that that's causing performance problems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All attributes declared as `static` belong to a class, as opposed to the non-static *instance* attributes, which are allocated for each object that gets instantiated. So yes, `static` attributes end up consuming "less memory" because they're created only once per all the class' instances.

But it's not right to think that you declare an attribute as `static` just to consume less memory, you create one because you want to share the same value among all the instances of the class, and that's more often than not a sign of a bad design. An exception is when an attribute is declared as `static final`, which means it has a constant value and can be safely declared at the class level.